# Customize drop down effect of spinner in Android device?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hi am here to ask how can we change the drop down style of a spinner of android as html  drop down menu.I know the normal spinner style can i change the spinner effect of the drop down in android if, so how i search the whole web it show only customizing the style of spinner cant find the solution that i needed example, i need to change the views as ***this***[image: normal spinner]

to ***this*** [image: custum dropdown spinner]

how can i do this?